# How to instantiate an fstream if you declare it as a member of a class?

Tags: c++, iostream

What constructor can you use to instantiate an fstream if you declare it as a member of a class?

```
#include <fstream>
class Foo {
Foo();
// not allowed
std::fstream myFile("\\temp\\foo.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);

// allowed
std::fstream myFile;
}
```

---

```
// constructor
Foo::Foo() {
// what form of myFile("\\temp\\foo.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc)  can I use here?


myFile = ???
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the new version of C++ (C++11), then the above code you have is perfectly fine; initializations are allowed inside the body of a class.

In C++03 (the previous version of C++), you can initialize the `fstream` by using the *member initializer list* like this:

```
Foo::Foo() : myFile("file-name", otherArguments) {
    // other initialization
}
```

Syntatically, this is done by adding a colon after the constructor name but before the brace, then listing the name of the field you want to initialize (here, `myFile`), and then in parentheses the arguments you want to use to initialize it.  This will cause `myFile` to be initialized properly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you expand on this new C++2011 feature allowing you to use "initializations are allowed inside the body of a class."? I was under the distinct impression that all members are readily initialized when the body of the constructor is entered...

Comment: @DietmarKühl- Sure!  In C++11, you can assign default values to each of the fields of a class.  If they aren't overridden by something specific in an initializer list, then they're initialized as if they were initialized in an initializer list.

Comment: @templatetypedef: oh, right: memberwise initializers in the class definition. Somehow I forgot about those! Thank you for claifying!

Comment: @templatetypedef Except the memberwise initialization requires `{}` instead of `()`, so OP's first code sample is *not* quite OK.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is:

```
Foo::Foo () {
    myFile.open("\\temp\\foo.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);

    if(!myFile.is_open()) {
        printf("myFile failed to open!");
    }

    //other initialization
}
```