# fstream initialization as a class

Tags: c++, constructor, fstream

before you mark it as duplicate, I have already read the following [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994157/how-to-instantiate-an-fstream-if-you-declare-it-as-a-member-of-a-class).

I have a simple Class called ATM:

ATM.h

```
class ATM {
public:
    ATM(Bank* ownerBank, const char* inputFile);
    ~ATM();
    void performSingleATMAction();
    friend void* performSingleATMActionFunc(void* pVoidATM);
private:
    Bank* ownerBank;
    string inputFile;
    fstream fileReader;
    Thread mainThread;
    static const unsigned int ATM_SLEEP_TIME = 1000*100;
};
```

I try to initialize it via initialization list:

```
ATM::ATM(Bank* ownerBank, const char* inputFile) :
ownerBank(ownerBank),
inputFile(inputFile), 
fileReader(inputFile,std::ifstream::in), // why copy constructor?
mainThread(performSingleATMActionFunc,this)
{}
```

the line
`fileReader(inputFile,std::ifstream::in)`

somehow invokes the copy constructor.. which is private

any help?

Comment: You probably have to post a complete examble that can be compiled and that shows the problem, as I can't reproduce the problem in a hacked up version that is based on the code you posted.

Comment: `// why copy constructor?` - what? There's no copy constructor there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out on a limb, you're probably copying objects of type `ATM`. Which - by default - copies all members.

This requires the copy constructor for the stream.

> Note: having a filestream a member of an ATM class is a design smell to me. ATM machines don't "have-a" file, usually. So, probably you need a (member) function to read "transactions" (just guessing)

Comment: indeed you were right. in class "Bank" I had a vector of ATM's where the push_back method invoked the ATM default copy constructor.